# Recurrence equation to solve

Tags: recurrence-relations

Given
$$x_k=(I-aP)x_{k-1}-aq$$
I need to prove that it is equal to
$$x_k=(I-aP)x_0-kaq$$

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: In order to improve your question use: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: writting down all equations up to x(0) and then sum them all together

Comment: and i get x(k)=(I-aP)x(0)-kaq-aP(x(k-1)+x(k-2)+...+x(1))

Comment: You should write in your question what you have tried, so that people can help you more efficiently. See also http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: This relationship is false.

Comment: If you have a correct formula for the answer, you can prove it by induction.

Comment: Is $I-ap$ idempotent?

Comment: P is positive definite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x_1=(I-aP)x_{0}-aqI\\
x_2=(I-aP)x_{1}-aqI\\
x_3=(I-aP)x_{2}-aqI\\
...\\
x_{k-1}=(I-aP)x_{k-2}-aqI\\
x_k=(I-aP)x_{k-1}-aqI$$

From that you can multiply equation $i$ by $(I-aP)^{k-i}$ and write:

$$(I-aP)^{k-1}x_1=(I-aP)^{k}x_{0}-(I-aP)^{k-1}aq\\
(I-aP)^{k-2}x_2=(I-aP)^{k-1}x_{1}-(I-aP)^{k-2}aq\\
(I-aP)^{k-3}x_3=(I-aP)^{k-2}x_{2}-(I-aP)^{k-3}aq\\
...\\
(I-aP)x_{k-1}=(I-aP)^2x_{k-2}-(I-aP)aq\\
x_k=(I-aP)x_{k-1}-aqI$$

Now you can sum every equation and get:

$$x_k=(I-aP)^{k}x_0-aq[I+(I-aP)+(I-aP)^2+...(I-aP)^{k-1}]$$

We also have:

$$[I+(I-aP)+(I-aP)^2+...(I-aP)^{k-1}][I-(I-aP)]=I-(I-aP)^k$$

If $P^{-1}$ exist and $a\ne 0$ then

$$I+(I-aP)+(I-aP)^2+...(I-aP)^{k-1}=\frac{1}{a}P^{-1}[I-(I-aP)^k]$$

Finaly the equation would be

$$x_k=(I-aP)^{k}x_0-qP^{-1}[I-(I-aP)^k]$$

**PS.: The relation that you are trying to prove is FALSE.**

Comment: question about your last two lines,you are summing matices,so does the relation you wrote holds?

Comment: Oh, $I$ and $P$ are matrices? You should write that in the statement

Comment: i wrote,but somehow that disappeared...

Comment: @Mika10: please take another look. The solution depends on $a$ and $P$ as I wrote. Need time, please, try to write a full statement.

Comment: Full task: Consider the subgradient method with constant step size a,uesd to minimize the quadratic function f(x)=1/2(x(trasposed)Px+q(transposed)x,P is positive semidefinite matrix.For which values of a do we have convergence? What values of a give the fastest asymptotic convergence?

Comment: Each iteration od subgradient is x(k+1)=x(k)-a(Px(k)+q)=(I-aP)x(k)-aq.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $x_k=y_k+b$ and then
$$ y_k+b=(I-aP)(y_{k-1}+b)-aq $$
Try to get a condition for $b$ such that $y_k=(I-aP)y_{k-1}$.